# Finding the constructor in multi-level inheritance

Tags: javascript

I want to find out the specific constructor used to instantiate the object in javascript, not the one which is last in the prototype chain. Consider the code :

```
function F(){};
function E(){};
function D(){};
function C(){};
function B(){};
function A(){};

E.prototype= new F();
D.prototype= new E();
C.prototype= new D();
B.prototype= new C();
A.prototype= new B();

a=new A();
```

Find fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k8o09v41/)

`a.constructor` returns `function F(){}`, but I want a method that returns `function A(){}`, since `A` is the constructor used to instantiate the object.

How can that be achieved ?

Comment: a.constructor.prototype gives me F.

Comment: I wrote a post about the "correct" way to setup inheritance in JavaScript http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: you may check [classy.js](https://github.com/classy,js) for java-like OOP functionality (and support for sweet.js) (i'm author)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way you inherit from parent it's not possible to access original constructor, because when you write

```
A.prototype = new B();
```

`A.prototype.constructor` indeed points to `B` not `A` anymore.

With this pattern for prototypical inheritance you have to manually set constructor properly. So you either do it for each extended class manually or you can use helper function:

```js
function inherit(C, P) {
    C.prototype = new P();
    C.prototype.constructor = C;
}

function F(){};
function E(){};
function D(){};
function C(){};
function B(){};
function A(){};

inherit(E, F);
inherit(D, E);
inherit(C, D);
inherit(B, C);
inherit(A, B);

var a = new A();
var c = new C()

document.write( a.constructor + "<br>" );
document.write( c.constructor );
```

Comment: You should teach the OP that instantiating the base class just to setup inheritance is bad. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html. use `C.prototype = Object.create(P.prototype);`

Comment: Thanks dfsq for pointing me in the right direction, I discovered over [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) that new operator for a constructor Foo creates a new object that inherits from Foo.prototype. Foo.prototype has the constructor property, by assigning A.prototype to new B(), the prototype object containing the  constructor property was essentially being over-ridden(all the way up to  E), leading to search in the prototype chain to the last Object of type F.Hence we need to assign constructor property ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
function F(){};
function E(){};
function D(){};
function C(){};
function B(){};
function A(){};

E.prototype= new F();
E.prototype.constructor = E;
D.prototype= new E();
D.prototype.constructor = D;
C.prototype= new D();
C.prototype.constructor = C;
B.prototype= new C();
B.prototype.constructor = B;
A.prototype= new B();
A.prototype.constructor = A;
```

Comment: `A.prototype.constructor = A;` should be sufficient, Isn't it?

Comment: If you are only interested in object `A`, then yes it's enough.

Comment: @sarbottam not really, you should fix the problem everywhere, the OP is clearly talking in general terms

Answer (score 0):

Did you check John Resig's Class.js ? http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/
It implements inheritance in javascript, and makes possible what you're asking for.

Edit: 
Sorry. I was wrong. However, you can add something like this to your declarations :

```
A.prototype= new B();
A.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Not sure of all the consequences it can have, but it seems to work!